# evaluate with jurassic js code, which modify html

Tags: javascript, c#, jurassic

I'm trying to reimplement getting captcha inside c# application. Having problem,  because of no experience in JS.

GET-request returns data, which contains captcha src tag, empty by default.

```
...
<div class="context"><img src="" id="capchaVisual" alt="loading..."></div>
...
```

It also returns some javascript, that fills captcha, like this:

```
function() {
var h = window.location.href;
if (h.indexOf("mytag") + 1) {
    var scr = $("#capchaVisual").attr("src");
    $("#capchaVisual").attr("src", scr + "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/MYCAPTCHADECODED...");
}
```

My steps in c# application:

1. Load json with data and scripts via [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx). Done. Result stored in jsonobject **answer**, where **answer.data** contains html, and **answer.e** - scripts to execute.
2. Try to execute loaded scripts via **Jurassic**:

   ```
       var engine = new Jurassic.ScriptEngine();
       engine.EnableDebugging = true;
       //engine.SetGlobalValue("window", answer.data);

       foreach (var line in answer.e)
       {
           var evalresult = engine.Evaluate(line);
           string t = evalresult.ToString();
       }
   ```

   Failed with: **ReferenceError: window is not defined**.
   If uncomment line 3 `engine.SetGlobalValue("window", answer.data)`, get anotwer error: **TypeError: undefined cannot be converted to an object**.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in [old Jurassic issues](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/discussions/243310).
My scripts uses DOM window object, but:

**paulbartrum
Jan 26, 2011 at 11:01 AM**

> No, sorry!
>
> Both of those frameworks rely on the existance of a browser DOM.  By
>   default, Jurassic can only run "pure javascript" like the CoffeeScript
>   compiler.
>
> Basically if a script does not reference "document" or "window" it
>   will probably work.